# instantiate and initialize multi dimensional array C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a multi dimensional array but i want to be able to instantiate and initialize it in one line does anyone know how to do this?

Here is what i have at the moment.

```
int[,] Columns = [3,2];
Columns[0,0]= 1;
Columns[1,0]= 0;
Columns[2,0]= 2;
Columns[0,1]= "Distinct";
Columns[1,1]= "Sum";
Columns[2,1]= "Distinct";
```

im trying to get somthing along the lines of:

[image]

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why does it suddenly turn in to a string array at line 5? And also, could you illustrate what your'e hoping to achieve somehow?

Comment: object[,] Columns = { { 1, "Distinct" }, { 0, "Sum" }, { 2, "Distinct" } };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, you can use something called a [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) with rectangular arrays! But you can't declare the array type as `int` and try and store strings (such as "Sum") in it too.

You could use the `object` type to store different data types in the same collection:

```
object[,] Columns = { { 1, 0, 2 }, { "Distinct", "Sum", "Distinct" } };
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :)